# Wordpress htaccess redirect conflict with Joomla plugin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

On the website there's a multiple installation of Wordpress and Joomla in the same root directory. 
I know this is a bad practice but I hope this will be only temporary.
The main site is in Wordpress, and I use Joomla for a newsletter plugin, AcyMailing. The latter uses an image to track the statistic for the newsletter; the problem is that the tracking doesn't work because the URL used for tracking purpouse -> "[http://www.eurolucelampadari.it/index.php?option=com_acymailing&ctrl=stats](http://www.euroluce.it/index.php?option=com_acymailing&ctrl=stats)" is being rewritten by Wordpress .htaccess. 
I tried using this rewrite rule to disable the redirection, but it's not working:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*acymailing.*$
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Is there an error in the rewrite rule or what I'm trying to do is wrong or impossible?

Thank you all!

Comment: I don't quite understand. Both WordPress and Joomla use index.php, and they both seem at the same level. Could you please provide a bit more insight about your structure?

Comment: Hi itoctopus, thank you for the response.
Yes, sure thing: as you told, they both reside at the same level; to avoid conflicts, I had to renamed both Joomla's index.php and .htaccess because the main site is in Wordpress. Now, the problem is here: the plugin used by Joomla doesn't "find" the htaccess rules from Joomla itself because the one active is related to WP. I stupidly thought that adding a rewrite rule would fix this, but I understand that they use different rules and structure.